# How to restore breakpoints in MATLAB after "clear all"?

Tags: matlab, breakpoints

I have a habit of beginning all my MATLAB scripts with `clear all; close all; clc`. While it has been a very useful line, as soon as it executes, it wipes out all my breakpoints. Is there a simple way to avoid that?

Comment: I guess the simplest way would be to use `clear` rather than `clear all`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have solved this issue by creating a script that saves and reloads breakpoints. For convenience, you can even put it into a shortcut.

```
%# store breakpoints
tmp = dbstatus;
save('tmp.mat','tmp')

%# clear all
close all
clear classes %# clears even more than clear all
clc

%# reload breakpoints
load('tmp.mat')
dbstop(tmp)

%# clean up
clear tmp
delete('tmp.mat')
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I understood most of the solution. What does the line `dbstop(tmp)` do?

Comment: I had one more question: how to put it into a shortcut?

Comment: @ShashankSawant: `dbstop(tmp)` sets the breakpoints stored in the variable `tmp`. To put it into a shortcut, find where it says "new shortcut" in your Matlab UI, and either copy-paste the solution there, or create a script and write the name of the script where you type the code to be run on execution of the shortcut.

Comment: Very nice solution! There seem to be a problem with breakpoints that are located in functions inside packages (For instance +MyPackage/MyFile.m) ; at least on 2012a it happens.

Comment: @Andrey: interesting. So it seems that `dbstatus` cannot access files not on the path. I guess that one would need to add a routine to (1) identify package directories, (2) `cd` into each of them, to (3) run `dbstatus` separately and (4) catenate the outputs. Since I don't use packages myself (I know, I know) I haven't run into the problem.

Comment: Great solution. Once case where it fails is with Matlab class methods due to a weird naming intricacy. In the `dbstatus` struct, class methods are stored as `classname.methodname` but they must be restored as `classname/methodname` (note the slash instead of a dot). So there should be an intermediate step after `tmp = dbstatus;` that replaces all dots in the `name` field with forward slashes.

Answer (score 8):

`clear all` is a heavy hammer. For example, it also dumps all the parsed MATLAB code already in memory. A simple `clear` or [one of the other options](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html) is usually a better choice and will not wipe your breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue : after running my code, all breakpoints were deleted. I finally found that you could restore your last breakpoints by clicking on "Set / clear breakpoints" (F12 keypad).