# How to create keyboard shortcuts to MATLAB scripts

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to set key bindings for a custom script in MATLAB?

I use several [custom shortcuts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/create-matlab-shortcuts-to-rerun-commands.html?searchHighlight=shortcuts+toolbar) on a regular basis (for workspace cleanup and [breakpoint loading and saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657219/how-to-restore-breakpoints-in-matlab-after-clear-all/12657328#12657328), for example) and would like to specify keyboard shortcuts for them, which is essentially specifying shortcuts for scripts. Is this possible?

**EDIT 1**: I found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24615-editormacro-assign-a-macro-to-a-keyboard-key-stroke-in-the-matlab-editor-and-command-window), but it is rather old, and provides a partial solution only. I have not yet tried it.

**EDIT 2**: This [MATLAB blog entry](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2007/03/29/shortcuts-for-commonly-used-code/) has this question in the comments (#28) with no answer. A similar question appears in the comments of [a different entry](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/09/28/configurable-keyboard-shortcuts-have-arrived/) about keyboard shortcuts (#23), again with no answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, any button on the quick-access toolbar is automatically assigned a keyboard shortcut of the form `Alt+1`, `Alt+2`, `Alt+3` etc., so if you place your script in a shortcut on the toolbar, it will have this associated keyboard shortcut, which can be viewed by pressing `Alt`.

This does not allow you to customize the key binding (besides the number, which is simply the button's location on the toolbar, from left to right), but it does provide for a handy way to run custom scripts with a simple keyboard shortcut.

Note also that any custom shortcut can also be accessed by pressing `Alt+S` and then the shortcut number as it appears in the shortcuts tab.

I am yet to find a solution for MATLAB on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that Matlab does not provide this functionality internally, you might try to use a shortcut at the desktop level. Matlab has a command line interface, and also accepts statements to evaluate as a command line argument. See here:
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html

The command line option I am referring to is `-r`.

I did not try this, it might very well be that the statement is not executed in the running session so it is not helpful for cleaning the workspace.

Comment: This will execute commands on startup, which can also be achieved using the [startup.m](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) file. I'm looking for a way to execute scripts _during_ the session.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that it always starts a new session instead of executing the command in the running session..